# Expandable list button clicks vs item clicks

Tags: android

I have an expandable list view whose each group item has button. Is there any way that I can differentiate the between the button clicks from the item clicks?
I want that button click to expand the list. While item click to open an activity

Thank you very much

EDIT: More explanation

Here is roughly what I am trying to do and right now I am thinking of using ExpandableListView but I dont know how to do it.

[image]
So as you can see, I have the group row has two portions the arrow (which I have it a customized arrow) and the text portion. If the user clicks on red portion then I want to expand (typical expandable list) and if the user clicks on the green portion then it takes them to an activity.

Please, any idea how!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the onGroupClickListener: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener.html

That will differentiate clicks in the group between clicks in the children.

Comment: That's what I am looking for. In my question, I am saying that my group has a button and I want to differentiate between click on group item vs click on group button

Comment: OH. You have a button _in_ the group? Well, there isn't necessarily a good way to do that, except by enabling the focusable mode of the button and setting the appropriate click listeners in your `ExpandableListAdapter`.

Comment: Please see the edit for more explanation of the problem. Thank you